# Spring/Vaadin Twitch oauth2 login

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, vaadin, twitch

I am trying to build a Vaadin/Spring application that would allow the users to log in either using a username/password that I store in a DB (this part I got covered with a `CustomAuthenticatorProvider`), or by clicking a button that would be "Login in with your Twitch account" and that would perform the auth using oauth2 on Twitch.

For this part, I am not able to find any solution...do I have to create another `CustomAuthenticatorProvider`? Is there a way to use the built-in oauth2 from Spring?

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: This will not be enough for an answer (i have no experience with oauth2), but I have found a tutorial to implement login with google oauth2, which will maybe help: https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/google-login

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: I know this tutorial, and it does work with Google because spring-security has some "magic" implemented for Google.

Comment: I do not have any code to show because I have no clue where to start. I have read tutorials about Spring + oauth2, Vaadin+Google oauth...but i am not able to see how I can merge this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spring Security OAuth 2.0 client with a Vaadin app. Here's a link to a [tutorial](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/google-login) with a demo app.

Comment: i have read this tutorial. It works because Spring comes prepared for Google oauth2. I have tried to build on this, but I cannot figure out how i can first adapt this to Twitch, and second, how I can mix this with another way of authenticating: let the user use either that "custom" account or their Twitch account.